# ElasticSearch - NEST Query Condition Limit

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

After searching on Google, i found the Elasticsearch max query condition limit is 1024?

Is it configurable? If yes can you anyone please provide the steps.

Thanks,
Sameer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default value is 1024, but it is configurable. In the elasticsearch configuration file (the yml file for example), set the mentioned setting: `index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 100000` for example.

Comment: Thank you very much Utsav.

I will test after adding the above mentioned settings in elasticsearch.yml.

Comment: Utsav, the settings you mentioned are working. Just to note - Query performance decreases as we add more conditions than 1024.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: There is a small change in the syntax as below - 
index.query.bool.max_clause_count: 10240

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have changed it in my answer. You can give me a thanks by giving a vote up and approving the answer.

Comment: Utsav, I approved your answer. Thank you so much for the help. I have another question which I asked separately. If you know the answer then please reply to it. Here is the link to the question - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28700963/elasticsearch-nest

Again, thank you very much.

Comment: If i will configure this it will consume more memory. any alternative solutions for this problem.