# Elasticsearch increase term limit

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this as part of a bool query

```
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "column1.raw": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "column1.raw": "value2"
          }
        }
      ]
```

Here the term section will repeat multiple times as per the value of an array which I am using to calculate it. If I limit this array to 500 it is working. But it is not working if the array count is greater than 1000. How can I increase this limit ? most of the times, I have above 4000 values in the array and so the term filter need to repeat for 4000 times. Is there any alternative method of doing the same ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - NEST Query Condition Limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637004/elasticsearch-nest-query-condition-limit)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

- http://george-stathis.com/2013/10/18/setting-the-booleanquery-maxclausecount-in-elasticsearch/

You can set the

```
index.query.bool.max_clause_count: n
```

parameter in the elasticsearch.yml file, where `n` is the number of terms you want to allow.